# Outlook Meeting Requests auto accept and delete

Tags: outlook, exchange-server-2010

We have a large amount of meeting requests we need to send out. We would like to prevent the users getting large amount of meeting requests to accept so I have found online the following script to auto accept meetings and then delete from inbox. This is the script:

```
Sub AutoAcceptMeetings(oRequest As MeetingItem)

If oRequest.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
Set oAppt = oRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)

Dim oResponse
 Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)
 oResponse.Send

oRequest.Delete

End Sub
```

What I now require is the ability to force all mailboxes in our exchange to run this script when receiving a Meeting request with a specified heading in the subject line.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a COM addin that runs that code and install it on all machines where you want to auto accept meeting requests.

If you do not want to check the subject of a request, you can configure each mailbox to auto accept all requests (File | Options | Calendar | Auto accept or decline).